# What is a well-known formula of the generalized Hardy Z-function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Q: What is a well-known formula of the generalized Hardy Z-function??

$\arg_0(z)=\frac{\log(z)-\log(\overline{z})}{2i}$

$a_{k,j}=\frac{1-\chi_{k,j}(-1)}{2}$

$\vartheta_{q,r}(z)=\frac{\log\Gamma(\frac14+i\frac{z}2+\frac12a_{q,r})-\log\Gamma(\frac14-i\frac{z}2+\frac12a_{q,r})}{2i}-\frac12z\log(\frac{\pi}{q})-\arg_0(L_{q,r}(\frac12))$

$Z_{q,r}(z)=e^{i\,\vartheta_{q,r}(z)}L_{q,r}(\frac12+iz)$

I could not find any formulas for the generalized Hardy Z-funcion yet!
The above formula of the Riemann-Siegel theta function is a well-known formula?

Answer (score 1):

Formulas for the analogous of the Z(t) function in the case of 
Dirichlet L-functions are known

For example see:
D. Davies, C. B Haselgrove, The evaluation of Dirichlet L-functions, Proc. of the Royal Society London. Series A  264 (1961) 122-132.

Comment: Thanks@juan : The next formula of (1.5) in {Davies,Haselgrove} seems to be an approximation formula for small t. I am finding an exact formula for all complex numbers...